# In Kubernetes can taint/toleration achieve all use-cases achievable using node affinity (and vice-versa)?

Tags: kubernetes

I understand that in Kubernetes `taint/toleration` is used to ensure that a node tainted with a label will only have pods with corresponding toleration to be scheduled on it. Also, through `node affinity` we (can) ensure that a pod gets scheduled on subset of nodes using labels.

However, I wanted to know if there are use-cases where what can be achieved by one, cannot be achieved by the other. Even scenarios where one might be preferred over the other, will be insightful.

Answer (score 3):

According to your statement `taint/toleration is used to ensure that a node tainted with a label will only have pods with corresponding toleration to be scheduled on it.` , but it is not always guaranteed that pod scheduled only that node. For example,

We have 3 nodes, **blue**, **green**, **red** node. and we also have 3 pods **B**, **G**, **R**. Our goal is to place the **B** pod in the **blue** node, the **R** pod in the **red** node likewise **G** pod in the **green** node. We are sharing the same kubernetes cluster with other teams, so there are *other pods* in the cluster as well as *other nodes*. We do not want any other pod to be placed on our node. Neither do we want our pods to be placed on their nodes.

If we apply taint on **blue** node, so that only blue pod can be scheduled on it, similarly apply taint on **green** node, which tolerate only green pod and **red** node tolerate red pods.

So, First **B** pod might be scheduled on blue pod, and **G** pod scheduled on green pod. and **R** pod can be ends up on other node.

If we want to solve same problem with node affinity. how can we do that?

We labeled **blue** node with blue color, **red** node with red color and **green** node with green color. We then set node selectors on the pod so that **B** pod scheduled on blue node, **G** pod scheduled on green node and **R** pod scheduled on red node.

So, here problem is, this does not guarantee that other pods are not placed on that node. so there is a chance that other pods may ends up on **blue**, **green** or **red** node.

With combination of *taints/toleration* and **node affinity** we can completely dedicated nodes for specific pod.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that in Kubernetes taint/toleration is used to ensure that a node tainted with a label will only have pods with corresponding toleration to be scheduled on it.

Yes the node will have pods which tolerate the taint. But the pods which tolerate the taint might also be scheduled to other nodes which doesn't have any taints.

> Also, through node affinity we (can) ensure that a pod gets scheduled on subset of nodes using labels.

Yes, with nodeAffinity you can **require** pods to be scheduled only on the matching nodes.